# !pip install numpy File "<stdin>", line 1 !pip install numpy ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, installation, pip, package

I'm trying to use pip to install a package. I try to run pip install from the Python shell, but I get a SyntaxError. Why do I get this error? How do I use pip to install the package?

Comment: This has nothing to do with visual studio, so I am removing that tag

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 2):

to install pip packages you need to do it from outside the python terminal. So if you open a cmd window and then do pip install it should work.

Answer (score 1):

To install the libraries using pip, you need to use terminal and then `pip install <package_name>, in this case` pip install numpy`.

Answer (score -1):

There
To install the numpay libraries, you need to use command prompt and then enter command **pip install <package_name>**, In you case **pip install numpy**.

Comment: What does this answer add that the other two have not covered yet?